# AngularJS - checkbox

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать выполнение некоторого действия в функции в контроллере при checked/unchecked checkbox? Скажем, при нажатии кнопки button - это `ng-click="имя_вызываемой_функции(передаваемые_параметры)"`, и в контроллере сама функция, а как то же самое сделать для чекбокса? Причем передавать его состояние выставлен/не выставлен, либо в зависимости от состояния вызывать две разных функции.

И как выставить изначальное значение чекбокса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем качественное решение, но если не хочется плодить функции в контроллере, то попробуйте вот так:

```
<input type="checkbox"
  ng-true-value="YES" 
  ng-false-value="NO" 
  ng-model="mycheckbox" 
  ng-change="mycheckbox=='YES' ? first() : other()" />
```

Comment: спасибо, а как задать изначальное значение на основе результата выполнения какой-то функции?

Comment: Просто присвоить значение модели `mycheckbox` (на самом деле лучше завести один объект под модель, то есть  `model.mycheckboxModel`). Тогда в `$scope` можно будет обратиться к значению модели.

Comment: спасибо! Подскажите, пожалуйста, а если на странице набор чекбоксов, как задать конкретному чекбоксу конкретное значение? У меня сейчас у каждого чекбокса  есть ng-model="myModel", в контролере я устанавливаю значение чекбокса через $scope.myModel = значение, значение устанавливается, но для всех чекбоксов сразу, т.к. у них модель одна. А как их можно идентифицировать по одиночке?

Comment: @Emm, вы добавляете `checkbox` вручную? Тогда и модели можно указать разные вручную, либо же пусть модель у вас будет массивом и вы с можете обращаться к ней по индексу. Либо же, используйте `ng-repeat` по модели с массивом элементов-значений.

Comment: В контроллере: `checkboxes = [ { name: "Первый чекбокс", cbState: false } , {"name": "Второй чекбокс", cbState: true } ]`

В разметке: `<span ng-repeat="cb in checkboxes"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="cb.cbState" /> {{cb.name}}</span>`

Comment: разные модели - т.е. `ng-model="myModel1"`, `ng-model="myModel2"`? А как тогда к ним в контроллере обращаться?  Не перебирать же все модели. Что-то типа `myModel + индекс`. Если модель - массив, тогда нужно задать модель всем чекбоксам как `ng-model="myModel[{{здесь вывожу текущий индекс}}]"`? А в контроллере тогда обращаться к конкретному чекбоксу через `$scope.myModel[индекс]`, верно?

Comment: я добавляю чекбоксы внутри ng-repeat, только ng-repeat - не для самих чекбоксов. Чекбоксы как дополнение :) Но начальное значение чекбокса должно устанавливать в зависимости от результата вычислений на основе элемента из ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type=checkbox ng-model=smth ng-change=doSmth(smth)>
```

Comment: спасибо, а как задать изначальное значение на основе результата выполнения какой-то функции?

Comment: @Emm, в контроллере `$scope.smth = someFunc();`.

Comment: спасибо! Подскажите, пожалуйста, а если на странице набор чекбоксов, как задать конкретному чекбоксу конкретное значение? У меня сейчас у каждого чекбокса  есть ng-model="myModel", в контролере я устанавливаю значение чекбокса через $scope.myModel = значение, значение устанавливается, но для всех чекбоксов сразу, т.к. у них модель одна. А как их можно идентифицировать по одиночке?